# Plesk server down, MySQL removed

Tags: mysql, plesk

Several hours ago, I realized that none of our sites work anymore, not even the Plesk interface.

When I try to access it I got the error:

> ERROR: Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or > directory
>
> Additionally, an exception has occurred while trying to report this error: > Zend_Exception
>   No entry is registered for key 'translate' (Abstract.php:144)

The server is on **Debian 7 wheezy**.

I can still log in using ssh and when I did so a few hours back I realized that mysql was totally missing. I don't know how it's possible but it looked like the package was removed.

Without mysql, no web interface for plesk, no repair utility, nothing works.

So I tried to reinstall it manually and got a lot of problems with packages not found and so on, it was a mess of searching on the web and trying for several hours.

Right now I'm to the point where I don't know what to do anymore, I have kind of installed mysql but it doesn't start, the server is totally broken and it starts to become worrying.

I did the following to install mysql :

```
cd /usr/src && sudo wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now I've got mysql:

```
~# mysql
mysql                       mysqlbinlog                     mysql_config_editor         mysqld_multi                mysql_embedded              mysqlimport                 mysql_setpermission         mysql_upgrade               
mysqlaccess                 mysqlbug                    mysql_convert_table_format  mysqld_safe                 mysql_find_rows             mysql_install_db            mysqlshow                   mysql_waitpid               
mysqlaccess.conf            mysqlcheck                  mysqld                      mysqldump                   mysql_fix_extensions        mysql_plugin                mysqlslap                   mysql_zap                   
mysqladmin                  mysql_config                mysqld-debug                mysqldumpslow               mysqlhotcopy                mysql_secure_installation   mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
```

But when I try to start it:

```
~# sudo service mysql start
Pas de rÃ©pertoire, connexion avec HOME=/
.190604 07:42:02 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
...................................................................................................................................................................................
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.6.40 did not start. Please check logs for more details..
```

The manipulation that may be at the origin of the incident it that we accidentally filled up the `rootfs` partition (the usage was 100% for maybe an hour or so).

So we started to receive weird error in the shell about missing storage space.

And that's where we may have made a mistake, we executed some commands to free some space (without thinking for one second they could remove such an important package as mysql....) :

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
```

If I remember correctly, none of these commands actually did anything, they all returned that no package have been uninstalled (I didn't pay much attention at the detail of the output so I could wrong but I have a strong conviction).

`rootfs` was in fact filled up by a huge archive downloaded in the wrong directory: `/tmp` instead of `/var/tmp`. The archive was 10GB.

After removing it, the fs looks ok:

```
~# df -h
Sys. fich.     Taille Util. Dispo Uti% MontÃ© sur
rootfs            20G  6,9G   12G  38% /
/dev/root         20G  6,9G   12G  38% /
devtmpfs          32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            6,3G  856K  6,3G   1% /run
tmpfs            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             13G     0   13G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md3         2,7T  1,7T  857G  67% /var
```

I gave you a lot of details, sorry for the long post, but the situation is desperate right now.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your case I would just backup all mysql data files from your server, in case you haven't already. Second, I would try to resolve the mysql startup errors. Try to stop any mysql services, which are running (maybe also check the pids) and have a look at the (sys)log for more details. What is the error you get when trying to start the mysql server now?

Comment: I just found this article: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214029749-MySQL-Server-service-is-missing-No-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Maybe it helps you resolving the issue! In your case the command will be something like "/usr/local/psa(?)/mysql/bin/mysqld" --install MySQL57 --defaults-file="/usr/local/psa(?)/mysql(?)/my.ini". The service might be called "mysql57" as mentioned in the article. I don't knwo if this only applies for windows servers.

Comment: Maybe there is and there shouldn't be any mysql installed. I found this thread https://talk.plesk.com/threads/how-do-you-restart-mysql.343314/ saying, that plesk uses mariadb (a fork of mysql). So the service and package is called maraidb(-server). You can check this with the command `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep -iE '(sql|db)'`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have no mysql service running and can't start a new one. I didn't backup anything because I don't know how to do it without `mysqldump`. When I try to dump a database I get the following error: `mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect`. Do you know a way to backup all databases without running any mysql command? Where are the files stored?

Comment: Have you checked if there is any maraiadb or similar service with the command `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep -iE '(sql|db)'`? The default data directory containg the databases should be `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: Yes I tried but `systemctl` is an unknown command.

Comment: Does the command `apt list --installed` shows something like `mariadb` or similar?